# Error for running rosbridge_websocket.launch

Tags: ros, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I compiled the rosbridge_suite package (develop branch). When I want to run roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch, I encounter with the following error:

```
 File "/home/users/al/catkin_ws/src/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_server/scripts/rosbridge_websocket", line 37, in <module>
    from rosauth.srv import Authentication
ImportError: No module named rosauth.srv
process[rosapi-3]: started with pid [23225]
[rosbridge_websocket-2] process has died [pid 23222, exit code 1, cmd /home/users/al/catkin_ws/src/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_server/scripts/rosbridge_websocket __name:=rosbridge_websocket __log:=/home/users/al/.ros/log/d36deb7c-e84b-11e4-b7bd-001aa0cf0b47/rosbridge_websocket-2.log].
log file: /home/users/al/.ros/log/d36deb7c-e84b-11e4-b7bd-001aa0cf0b47/rosbridge_websocket-2*.log
```

Please let me know how to solve it.

Best

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207535/error-for-running-rosbridge_websocket.launch/) by [Robatics1](https://answers.ros.org/users/20457/robatics1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robatics1](https://answers.ros.org/users/20457/robatics1/) on 2015-04-21**:
You are right the rosauth was missing. worked. Thanks.

**Comment by [JackWu](https://answers.ros.org/users/84161/jackwu/) on 2021-11-30**:
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-rosauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you make sure to download and compile [rosauth](http://wiki.ros.org/rosauth) and all of rosbridge_server's other dependencies?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flynneva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44351/flynneva/) on 2020-06-13**:
[here is a link](https://github.com/GT-RAIL/rosauth) to the source for anyone who needs it since its not yet added to the wiki